# Finiding most common combinations of values in a dataset - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks more or less like this:

```
data = {'item_name':  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'],
        'order_id': ['1', '1', '2', '2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['item_name','order_id'])

item_name   order_id
a              1
b              1
c              2
a              2
```

I'd like to find the most common combinations of items within the same order. For example if it's a+b, or b+c.

I was thinking about using `pandas groupby()`, but it only counted the most popular items without giving me pairs.

```
most_common_combinations = data1.groupby(['order_id','item_name']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)

order_id  item_name                         
926       Chicken Bowl                          9
1786      Chicken Bowl                          5
926       Steak Bowl                            5
1586      Chicken Burrito                       4
205       Chicken Bowl                          4
```

What I would like to get is

```
Combo        Times ordered
a+b+c            50
a+b+d            40
c+b              10
```

I don't necessarily need the exact number e specific combo occured but know which combos were most common.

Can I use `groupby()` or some other pandas function to find these combos?
I'd appreciate your suggetions.

Thank you in advance,
Asia

Comment: Could you post the expected output based on the example for verification?

Comment: @anky - sure, just edited

Comment: The output doesnot relate to the input. how would you justify the `Times ordered` column based on the input?

Comment: Every order_id is a real order placed - I wanted to find out what sort of products were most commonly bought together. I might be wrong here, but thought this could be done given the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to group `item_name` per `order_id` and then use `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('order_id')['item_name'].unique().astype(str).value_counts()
```

Edit: Here's some extended sample data.

```
data = {'item_name':  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
    'order_id': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['item_name','order_id'])
df.groupby('order_id')['item_name'].unique().astype(str).value_counts()
```

This produces:

```
['a' 'b']    2
['c' 'a']    1
Name: item_name, dtype: int64
```